# Azure DevOps PDF Export Pulgin Suggestion

Tags: azure, plugins, azure-devops, export, report

I used jenkins to build jobs, and got a pdf report through restful api in worksapce
And use the "HTML Publisher" plugin to render the pdf report in the job summary download

Now I need to move to azure devops to work, azure devops also has "HTML Publisher" too,
But there is no way to present it like jenkins

Are there any similar plugins for jenkins HTML Publisher on Azure that allow me to see reports or download them in the summary?
Or are there other way that can provide report presentation?
(Compressed into a zip file, display pdf directly, or other methods ...)

Answer (score 1):

For this issue ,does the report you want refer to Pipeline Analytics? You can gain visibility into your team's pipeline(s) using Pipeline analytics. The source of information for pipeline analytics is the set of runs for your pipeline. These analytics are accrued over a period of time, and form the basis of the rich insights offered.

A summary of the pass rate and duration can be viewed in the Analytics tab of a pipeline. To drill into the trend and insights, click on the card to view the full report.

[image]

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/reports/pipelinereport?view=azure-devops). If this report is not what you want, please kindly let me know, and describe in detail what kind of report you want, I will continue to help you after understanding.

Comment: After I execute a task
I will use the rest API to get a PDF report
ex. curl --header "$HEADER" --data $DATA $API -o Report.pdf example.com
This file will save in Job's workspace
I wants to see it directly on the job or can be download in extension page .
Unlike full job analysis.

Comment: Currently,publishing html report in Azure pipelines is not supported in Azure Devops.You can refer to this [uservoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html).In addition,what analysis do you want to get in the report?( ie: code coverage ...) I will look for workaround based on these specific contents.

Comment: I added open source scanning tool during job build
This tool will automatically upload the results to its database after the scan is complete
But I don't want to go to the website to see the results
So download this report to workspace via curl
and wants to display or download this PDF report in the job summary extension